# add watch not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I right-click in the **Watch 1** window and select **Add Watch** but nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *very* unintuitive.  The command doesn't do anything beyond adding a new row and selecting it.  You next type the name of the variable.  More intuitive is right-clicking an identifier name in the editor window + Add Watch.  Or drag + drop it into the Watch window.

Answer (score 2):

Right click (in your code) on the variable or expression (select it) you want to watch. It will be added to the Watch window.

Answer (score 1):

Little question, large answer! You give us few details of what is happening...

Summarizing, be sure that current statement is around the place where your desired watched variables are, so you can see them on debug mode, i.e.:

1. Place a break point near there (press F9). Remember that it must be where the variable exists (remember that on C/C++/C# a common variable created inside brackets ({ and }) will be inaccessible outside it - something like that occurs on other languages);
2. Run the program (F5) and do something that let you on the right place (like pressing a button that launches the function where there are variables you want to watch);
3. To choose a variable to watch, on debug you must press mouse right button on it and "add watch". "Walk towards" using debug functions step into (F11), step out (shift+F11), step over (F10) or run-until-next-break-point (F5).